# How can StyledMapType layers that use JSON styles be replaced by Google's Cloud-based Map Styles?

Tags: google-maps

We have an app that makes extensive use of Google Maps JavaScript API code like the following:

```
new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleJSON, { name: 'Overlay' })
```

We are overlaying these styled Google Maps layers on top of our own raster map tiles, so that map features that are covered by our raster map tiles (like roads, labels, etc) will still be visible. For example, our layers might look like this:

```
2 - A StyledMapType layer of Google's Road Features styled with JSON, overlayed with overlayMapTypes
1 - An ImageMapType layer of our own raster tiles overlayed with overlayMapTypes
0 - Google's Base Map
```

Since Google [recently announced that JSON Map styles will be deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/new-map-style-opt-in), and there is also a deprecation notice on the top of [the StyledMapType documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple), we are looking for a way to implement the same functionality with cloud-based styles.

How can we create an overlay layer of Google Maps features using the new cloud-based styles? We don't necessarily need JSON styles to do this, but we at least need a way to add a cloud-based map style as an overlay layer using `overlayMapTypes`.

Comment: I got a response from Google's support: "For the time being, no changes are planned that would affect how StyledMapType works."